# What would be the most efficient way to multiply hourly information with monthly information in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
rng_H = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2024', end='31/12/2050', freq='H')
df_H = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng_H, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng_H))})

rng_M = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2024', end='31/12/2050', freq='M')
df_M = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng_M, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng_M))})
```

What would be the most efficient way to multiply hourly information with monthly information? Please note that the monthly information would be fixed for the entire month, like the monthly price of electricity and my hourly information is the electricity needed (df_H). How can I do this efficiently preferably without converting the monthly information to hourly information? [1]

[1] I do not want to do that, because I can imagine that this is not very memory efficient, especially if I also somewhere along the line have quarterly information.

Please note, I am only interested in the outcome (i.e. one column of values) on hourly basis.

Please do not aggregate to monthly basis, but it should be hourly based.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need multiple hours aggregated by `sum` and ouput is in `month DataFrame` use:

```
df_M = df_M.set_index('Date')

df_M['New'] = df_M['Val'].mul(df_H.resample('M', on='Date')['Val'].sum())
print (df_M)
                 Val        New
Date                           
2024-01-31  1.216517 -14.457129
2024-02-29 -0.864238  23.484127
2024-03-31  1.069003  47.640310
2024-04-30  1.582702  34.242115
2024-05-31  2.218555  69.440245
             ...        ...
2050-08-31  0.991703  -8.968337
2050-09-30  0.243081   4.934752
2050-10-31  0.541675  -0.834577
2050-11-30  0.946118 -11.954840
2050-12-31 -0.037487  -1.815547

[324 rows x 2 columns]
```

If need multiple month values to hours DataFrame:

```
s = df_M.set_index('Date')['Val']
new = df_H.assign(new = df_H['Date'].dt.normalize() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd())['new'].map(s)
df_H['New'] = df_H['Val'].mul(new)
print (df_H)
                      Date       Val       New
0      2024-01-01 00:00:00 -1.478487 -1.602556
1      2024-01-01 01:00:00  1.206845  1.308119
2      2024-01-01 02:00:00 -0.915872 -0.992729
3      2024-01-01 03:00:00  1.615605  1.751181
4      2024-01-01 04:00:00  1.286935  1.394931
                   ...       ...       ...
236660 2050-12-30 20:00:00  0.609330 -0.381144
236661 2050-12-30 21:00:00 -1.443046  0.902644
236662 2050-12-30 22:00:00 -0.729726  0.456453
236663 2050-12-30 23:00:00 -0.281550  0.176113
236664 2050-12-31 00:00:00 -1.454502       NaN

[236665 rows x 3 columns]
```